# How to convert Byte* to LPCWSTR in wince6.0?

Tags: windows-ce

I have a structure say for an example

typedef struct {
    DWORD   time;
    BYTE*   message;
    DWORD   size;
} ACCP_MESSAGE_COMMAND_PARAM_T;

Now this is common to both master and client end and through master we r requesting to client with the following data 20,"MessageRequest",30.

Now at client side i want to display the message which is requested by master using %s.
But i am able to display only through %c not by %s..
Moreover if iam converting BYte* to LPCWSTR how should i achieve? Bcz whenever i am doing so it throws an exception..

Please Reply
Thanks 
Abhineet Agarwal

Comment: Are you using Windows Mobile6 or Windows CE6?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on Unicode.  Your data in your question ("MessageRequest") is not the same as in you comments (**L**"MessageRequest").  They are way different, and you need to understand that.  Look at the memory view to see how they are layed out.

You've not said how you want to "display" the message, but if it's still Unicode, and the client is CE-based, then there's nothing to do.  CE only uses Unicode for all of it's APIs.  If its the desktop, use a Wide ("W" suffixed) API, or #define UNICODE in your app.  Or convert it using wcstombs or WideCharToMultiByte.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending the string in unicode?
There is no TEXT() macro surrounding the string so I guess not. Try to print it with %S.

Comment: In any case it is not coming. it throws the following exception:

43929 PID:386000a TID:20a000e Exception 'Data Abort' (4): Thread-Id=020a000e(pth=94f994c8), Proc-Id=0386000a(pprc=97f54c20) 'onesegapp.exe', VM-active=0386000a(pprc=97f54c20) 'onesegapp.exe'
  43930 PID:386000a TID:20a000e PC=40065470(coredll.dll+0x00055470) RA=40070a94(coredll.dll+0x00060a94) SP=0026fa1c, BVA=00000002
  53957 PID:3b30006 TID:3ca0006 Master accp_callback CALLED
  53961 PID:3b30006 TID:3ca0006 ACCP_MSG_RES_ERROR CmdId:50397184 AppKind:3 param:&afd74

Comment: Does the message contain the termination? What is the size used for?
Why don't you pass LPWSTR in the first place?

Comment: Is the message sent as widechar in the first place? Look in the debugger how each character is represented. A wide char should occupy 2 bytes.

Comment: Did you try and look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202786.aspx

Comment: At first i took LPCWSTR msg =  L"MessageRequest";
then I stored the above value at MessageRequest.message=(BYTE*)msg;

Comment: After that at client side i recieve this message in BYTE* form.

Comment: Now my task is to print this message.. But the problem which i m getting is that i am not able to print in %s form 
Secondly i am not able to typecast in LPCWSTR type. if i do so i get an exception..

Comment: I am not too familiar with WinMo and it's WinCE 5 core. Are you sure the client can access the whole buffer without access violation? The seems that there are no problems if you can print it char by char. I'm just laying my thoughts here.

Comment: No actually we have to dump that message on a particular place say for an example MessageStatus window so in that case %c concept will not work out.
Plz reply
Thanks

Comment: Maybe it is me being thick headed, but can you updated the question stating exactly what it is you are doing (MFC, the code at the server, the code at the client + anything else that may be helpful). That way even if I can't see the problem someone else will find it easier to find it.

Comment: See there is master end and client end
At mAster end
there is a function which makes request to client
bool MessagePackageReq(BYTE scrap)
{
 LPCWSTR msg = L"MessageRequest";
 ACCP_MESSAGE_COMMAND_PARAM_T MessageRequest; 
 MessageRequest.size = 30;
 MessageRequest.message = (BYTE*)msg;
 MessageRequest.time = 40;
 DWORD cmdid;
 INT value,target,kind;
 LPVOID param = &MessageRequest;
 target = ACCP_APP_1SEG;
 kind =  ACCP_CMD_CON_MESSAGE;
  
 if(req)
 {
  value=req(&cmdid, target, kind, param);
  if(value == 0)
   return true;
 }
 return false;
}

Comment: And at client side there is a call back function

Comment: INT accp_callback(INT message, DWORD id, INT app_kind, LPVOID param)
{
 switch(message)
 {

Comment: case ACCP_MSG_CON_MESSAGE:
  {
   ACCP_MESSAGE_COMMAND_PARAM_T * par = (ACCP_MESSAGE_COMMAND_PARAM_T*)param;
   for(UINT i=0;i<((par->size)/2);i++){
    RETAILMSG(1,(TEXT("%c"),*par->message));    
    m1[i] =*par->message;
    par->message = par->message + 2;
   }   
   RETAILMSG(1,(TEXT("Message =%s, Size = %u, Time = %u\n"),m1,par->size,par->time));
   res(id, app_kind, message - ACCP_CMD_NUM, NULL);
}

Comment: Here m1 is a global variable of type BYTE m1[100];

Comment: I'll read this soon, but it better to update the question itself and not add this data as comments

Comment: Try to make the msg variable global or allocate it using malloc. I think you have a problem with leaving the scope of the allocated msg.

Comment: Why don't you use a msgqueue? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885180.aspx

Comment: I can't help more than this. Update the question describing what you are trying to achieve and what you have done so far. Then post the code you use now with the line that causes the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Well i got the solution for it.

If you want to convert BYTE* to LPCWSTR other than using WideCharToMultiByte then we can use in the following way:

```
BYTE * message; 
message="MessageRequest";
WCHAR msg[100]; 
msg = (WCHAR)message; //Copy "message" content into "msg" .
LPCWSTR msg1;  //Taken variable of LPCWSTR type 
msg1=(LPCWSTR)msg;
```

And then display it using **DrawText(...);** on the window 
And u will be able to see proper message.

Comment: This assumes that the BYTE* points to data that is already wide character, not multibyte, so this is *not* the same thing.  In fact you could have just cast the BYTE* to a TCHAR*, or done a simple memcpy to your new location.

Comment: No there was some problem in dll because of which i was getting problem 
so on doing in above method my problem was solved. the byte* value was imported from the dll which was displayed in %s way only through the above method. Anyway the comment which u send is absolutely right when i checked for the other examples other than my dll which was creating problem for all the method.